# Gitolie personal branches

Tags: git, namespaces, branch, gitolite

It is my first attempt to setup a git server and I try to manage it through gitolite. The documentation is very detailed and really helped me set the first rules for a master branch. 
Below is part of my conf file that describes the access on my master branch.

```
repo @my_repos
    RW+ master    =   @maintainer
    R   master    =   @engineers
    -   master    =   @engineers
    RW+           =   @engineers
```

What I want to do now is let the users create their own branches on demand in order to push their changes. I want these branches to follow certain access rules (e.g. The creator can RW+ and the rest R). My initial thought was to follow the personal branches concept.

In the personal branches page (http://gitolite.com/gitolite/special.html#pers) the author states that "Personal branches exist in a namespace of their own". That made me think that I should enable the namespaces support as explained here: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/namespaces . However, the entire namespace documentation refers into creating repositories under a namespace, not branches.

So my question is should I enable the namespaces or the personal branches are created "somehow" that I haven't learnt already or missed somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want users to be able to push to branches that include their names, then the [personal branches](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/special.html#pers) feature (i.e. include `/USER/` in a [refex](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/refex.html)) should suffice:

```
repo @my_repos
    RW+ master         =   @maintainer  # only maintainer can write to master
    RW+ personal/USER/ =   @engineers   # engineers can write to their own branches like personal/name/mybranch
    R                  =   @engineers   # all engineers can read all refs (branches/tags/etc.), including others' "personal" branches
```

Note: You can change `personal` to any (non-empty) prefix that suits your whims, but you must include `/USER/` verbatim (exactly those six characters).

For example, the engineer user named `alice` could push/force-push/delete any branches under `personal/alice/` (e.g. `personal/alice/ticket-1234`, `personal/alice/wip/frob-support`, et cetera), and all the other engineers could read these.

The documentation mentions “namespace” because the (e.g.) `personal/alice/` prefix forms a *space* in which `alice` may manipulate branch *names*.

---

The [namespace support](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/namespaces) is about serving a single repository (with a bit of extra data from the [`refs/namespaces/` refs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces.html)) as a set of related repositories. For example, such support would allow you to efficiently store and serve a main `git@host:frobozz` repository and a set of related `git@host:alice/frobozz`, `git@host:bob/frobozz`, and `git@host:carol/frobozz` repositories.

As noted in the gitolite documentation, you have to use a special version of *gitolite* to get this feature: it is only available under a special branch of the main *gitolite* repository (this branch is also a bit out of date at the time of writing, so it is missing other features and fixes that are present in master—a merge could probably help fix this, but still: not currently up to date).